# Spring Boot Authorization returning 401 error?

Tags: angular, spring, security, request, http-status-code-401

I have the problem that when I'm successfully logged in, I want to make a request to get the user details.
the request I am sending is an secured GET request which is `https://localhost:8080/users/userOne` this request is send by my Angular frontend.

But my problem now is, Spring Boot is telling me that the user isn't authorized and sending an 401 error. 
I'am sending an Authorization token when I make the request from frontend to backend. In my code below you can see what I'am doing.

**Angular Service**:

```
  getUserDetails(username) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', this.cookieService.get('token')).append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/users/` + username, { headers }).pipe(
      map(
        userData => {
          console.log(userData);
          return userData;
        }
      ));
  }
```

**My UserController:**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/", maxAge = 3600)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByUsername (@RequestBody String username){
        final User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
}
```

**My WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/authenticate").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().formLogin().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

**My Filter**

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
```

**Authentication request in Angular:**

```
authenticate(username, password) {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
      });
      return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/authenticate', {username, password}).pipe(
       map(
         userData => {
          sessionStorage.setItem('username', username);
          sessionStorage.setItem('token', userData.token);
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          return userData;
         }
       )
      );
    }
```

The Error I'm getting:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/users/userOne 401
```

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/users/Bogatom", ok: false, …}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I would have expected a 404 instead of 401. You are sending the username as part of the path not as the request body.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'am getting the 401 error the request I make is correct so far I know.

Comment: It isn't, not according to the mapping in the controller you have.

Comment: @M.Deinum And how do I fix that? can you make an edit?

Comment: No I'm not going to edit your question as that modifies the question. As stated in your JS  you are sending the username as part of the URL (the path) not as the body of the request. So either your URL on yuor controller needs to change and use an `@PathVariable` or your JS to send the username as the body.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a POST call at `http://localhost:8080/login` with following as headers of this request

`headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "X-XSRF-TOKEN": csrf_token
        }`

and credentials encoded using urlencode in the body of the request

`credentials = {
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        }`

The response of this request would contain elements like 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' and/or JSESSIONID which you need to pass while making all subsequent requests to `http://localhost:8080/users` or any other URL that is authorized.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I've made an Edit where you can see my Authentication request in Angular.

Comment: Firstly, I think you should change 'Content-Type' in headers to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of 'application/json' since you are using formLogin() in WebSecurityConfig. Secondly, apart from that just pass the credentials json to urlencode() method and send the encoded result of urlencode in body of the request. That should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to send a get request using a 3rd party application like postman or ARC. If it works, then you'll know that the token is not added correctly in angular.
But if it didn't work, the problem may be in the spring security configuration. In this case, for test purposes, permit all requests for the **"/users"** path, and see what you'll get, then add:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/users/**")
            .hasAuthority(authirty_name)
```

to permit users to get this resource.